# Dropdown sets as System.Data.DataRow, What is wrong with my code?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, drop-down-menu, datatable, dataset

```
    System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
    CDbAccess db = new CDbAccess();
    IDbConnection conn = db.GetConnectionInterface();
    conn.Open();
    string str = "select eName from bt_modules";
    IDbCommand cmd = db.GetCommandInterface(str);
    IDbDataAdapter da = db.GetDataAdapterInterface(cmd);
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    dt = ds.Tables[0];
    DropDownList2.DataSource = dt;
    DropDownList2.DataBind();
    conn.Close();
```

The above code set Dropdown items as `System.Data.DataRow`

How to get the actual values?

Comment: Google will help with this - pretty basic

Comment: where you want to get the data which is are in dropdownlist2?

Comment: @SATSON i want to bind the DropDownList2 Using Vb.net

Comment: @SATSON it set Dropdown items as `System.Data.DataRow` instead of Names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this :

```
 DropDownList2.DataSource = dt;
 DropDownList1.DataTextField = "eName " '// Column Name
 DropDownList2.DataBind();
```

If you want to use value field also using like this

```
 DropDownList2.DataSource = dt;
 DropDownList1.DataTextField = "eName " '// Column Name
 DropDownList1.DataValueField = "eid" '// Column Name
 DropDownList2.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 2):

`DropDownList2.DataSource = ds;`

`DropDownList2.DataTextField = "eName";`

`DropDownList2.DataBind();`

`conn.close();`

You can refer this code also http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/10/showbind-data-to-aspnet-dropdownlist.html